# Subscribe to an observable within a loop in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm having a use case where I need to subscribe to an `Observable` then looping the response in order to subscribe to another `Observable` using a data from the first `Observable`.

```js
  getTasks(taskType: Observable<any>): void {
    taskType // Subscribing to the first Observable
      .subscribe(
        (tasks: any) => {
          let row: InboxTasks;
          for (const task of tasks) { // Looping through the result
            if (task.assigned_id) { // I need to extract that data in order to use it as an argument of the second Observable below
              this.auth.getUserById(task.assigned_id).subscribe((user) => this.username = `${user.firstname} ${user.lastname}`);
            }
            row = {
              assigned: this.username ? this.username : '', // Here I use my newly created property
              task: task.displayName
            };
            this.rowData = [
              ...this.rowData,
              row
            ];
          }
        }
      );
  }
```

Using that method the loop while be executed before the second `Observable` can be complete.
How can I manage to use this second `Observable` in that scenario?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can first gather all inner Observables based on the response from the first Observable and wait until all of them complete with `forkJoin`:

```
taskType
  .pipe(
    concatMap(tasks => {
      const observables = [];
      for (const task of tasks) {
        observables.push(this.auth.getUserById(task.assigned_id));
      }
      return forkJoin(...observables).pipe(
        map(innerResults => ({
          innerResults,
          tasks
        }))
      );
    })
  )
  .subscribe(({ innerResults, tasks }) => ...);
```

Comment: Thanks but by using this solution the subscribe will only give me the results from getUserById Observable. What I want is loop through the tasks and subscribing to getUserById only if task.assigned_id exists. Then the response from getUserById (and the response from the first Observable!) will allows me to create the `row` object.

Comment: You can map the result from the inner `forkJoin` response to contain also first response. See my update.

Comment: sometimes my `observables` array has not length because sometimes my task has no assigned_id (which is a normal behaviour). But if that scenario happens then the `subscribe` won't work as `observables` is empty thus the `forkJoin` doesnt work (this is my guess). How can I get into the subscribe even if `observables` is empty?
Thanks